# Compose desktop "ClassNotFoundException" when using "verticalScroll" modifier

Tags: compose-desktop, jetbrains-compose

I am getting `ClassNotFoundException` error when using `verticalScroll` modifier, I am getting the same error when using LazyColumn too.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: androidx.compose.ui.input.mouse.MouseScrollFilter_skikoKt
```

I am using compose version `1.0.1` but its same with `1.0.0`

```
kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.10"
id("org.jetbrains.compose") version "1.0.1"
```

Can anyone help me to solve this ?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Check out if you can reproduce something as basic as `LazyColumn { items(100) { Text(it.toString()) } }` in a newly created project.

Comment: Thanks @PhilipDukhov, Sorry I was using ```implementation("org.jetbrains.compose.material:material-icons-extended:1.2.0-alpha01-dev606")``` instead of ```implementation(compose.materialIconsExtended)```. Its solved now.